# Listar os telefones na mesma linha

Tags: mysql, sql

eu tenho um banco de dados que tem as seguintes tabelas: contato, telefone e tabela contato_telefone já que a cardinalidade na minha aplicação tem que ser N:N. Quando eu faço um inner join, o retorno me traz, por exemplo, 3 registros se forem três telefones, 4 registros se forem 4 e assim por diante. Eu preciso agrupar os telefones em único registro, já que só essa informação muda, como por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
CREATE DATABASE Agenda;
USE Agenda;

CREATE TABLE contato(

 id_contato INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 tipo_contato INT NOT NULL,
 nome_contato VARCHAR(50),
 empresa_contato VARCHAR(50),
 cargo_funcao VARCHAR(25),
 departamento VARCHAR(20),
 CONSTRAINT pk_contato PRIMARY KEY(id_contato)
);

CREATE TABLE telefone(

 codigo_telefone INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 tipo_telefone INT NOT NULL,
 operadora VARCHAR(10),
 numero_telefone VARCHAR(20),
 CONSTRAINT pk_telefone PRIMARY KEY(codigo_telefone)
);

CREATE TABLE contatoTelefone(

 contato_telefone INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 contato INT NOT NULL,
 telefone INT NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_contato_telefone PRIMARY KEY(contato_telefone),
 CONSTRAINT fk_contato_fone FOREIGN KEY(contato) REFERENCES 
 contato(id_contato),
 CONSTRAINT fk_fone_contato FOREIGN KEY(telefone) REFERENCES 
 telefone(codigo_telefone)
);
```

E o select:

```
SELECT contato.*, telefone.*, contatotelefone.* FROM contato
INNER JOIN contatotelefone ON contato.id_contato = 
contatotelefone.contato_telefone
INNER JOIN telefone ON contatotelefone.contato_telefone = 
telefone.codigo_telefone;

Para ver como está a relação contato/telefone, ou só dou um select na tabela 
contatotelefone:

SELECT * FROM contatotelefone;
```

Como posso fazer isso no mysql? Tem como resolver de forma dinâmica?

Obs.: cada contato pode ter no máximo 4 número de telefones registrados.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: você tem que fazer isso no SQL, não pode ser na lingugem de programação?

Comment: Passa o select ou a estrutura de tabela.

Comment: group_concat https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat concatenando apenas ou https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320631/how-to-pivot-a-table-in-mysql-using-case-statements com case (pivot)

Comment: O ideal seria em SQL Guilherme Costamilam, porque eu preciso usar para preencher os campos quando o usuário usa botões de navegação (primeiro, anterior, próximo e ultimo) e creio que s fosse resolver tudo na programação, ficaria muito carregado o código. Além do mais, creio que seja mais correto isso vir do banco já 'montado' para manter uma certa independência. De qualquer forma, estou aberto a sugestões.

Comment: Então @Motta, mas o concat retornaria todos os telefones na mesma coluna, e seria interessante se cada número ocupasse a sua coluna. Além disso, se eu tiver que definir os valores para cada ocorrência, fica inviável.

Comment: Se tiver um indicar do "número" do telefone use o CASE (https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/564923-left-outer-join-duplicando/?do=findComment&comment=2250340)

Comment: Tentou por `PIVOT` ?

Comment: Sim, na verdade eu procurei bastante na rede entes de postar aqui. Vi alguns exemplos e até tentei adaptar para o meu problema, mas nenhum resolveu, porque a maioria deles usa uma função de agregação sobre número, como por exemplo SUM() ou MAX() e colocam o resultado sob colunas conforme um número de corte, o que não vem a ser o caso.